# How to prevent PHP mailer from receiving "outside submissions"

Tags: php

I use this syntax in the headers of PHP mailer to prevent receiving outside server submissions, it is working good for "www", but it does not work for incoming submissions from address without "www". How to fix it to work with both www and none www?

```
if($ref !== 'https://www.domain.xyz/dev/contact_us_form.php')
{
    die("Access Denied!");
}
```

Comment: why not strip the uri of www before comparison and just use that against a value you want?

Comment: @treyBake Is it possible to add the none "www" in this syntax, such "and if" statement?

Comment: sure, just use `str_replace()` to strip the www and then compare that against whatever value

Comment: How are you populating the `$ref`-variable? Sounds like you're looking for [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) protection. If you search on something like _"php csrf"_ and you will find multiple tutorials about it and a bunch of ready made libraries you can use.

Comment: I hope you're not using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to determine where the request came from, since that's a highly unreliable header. It's optional (and some routers/firewalls actually remove it for privacy reasons) and can be manipulated.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
$allowedDomains = [
    'https://www.domain.xyz/dev/contact_us_form.php',
    'https://domain.xyz/dev/contact_us_form.php',
];
if(in_array($ref, $allowedDomains) === false) {
    die("Access Denied!");
}
```

Though, [@treyBaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7611062/treybake) is right, you should strip `http(s)` and `www` before checking.
So what you should do is :

```
$host = str_replace('www.', '', parse_url($ref, PHP_URL_PORT));
if ($host  !== 'domain.xyz')
{
    die("Access Denied!");
}
```

If you also need to check for `/dev/contact_us_form.php` you can change it to

```
$parsedRef = parse_url($ref); // so we only parse $ref once
$host = str_replace('www.', '', $parsedRef['host']);
$path = $parsedRef['path'];
if ($host  !== 'domain.xyz' || $path !== '/dev/contact_us_form.php')
{
    die("Access Denied!");
}
```